# Pointing to outer-class C++

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, hierarchical-data

Here, i am trying to create a Nth level hierarchy but doesnt let me point to outer-class of an inner class and getting an access violation error. But the latter version workes.

What is my mistake? Is this about the scope of newly created inner-loops? But they are created inside the class so it shouldnt be problem should it?

```
 // atom.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

class a
{
public:
    int x;
    a * inner;
    a * outer;
    a(int n)   //creates an inner a
    {
        n--;
        x=n;    
        if(n>0){inner=new a(n);}else{inner=NULL;}   
        inner->outer=this;//Unhandled exception at 0x004115ce in atom.exe: 0xC0000005:
                          //Access violation writing location 0x00000008.
    }

};

int main()
{
    a * c=new a(5);
    a * d=c;
    while((d->inner))     //would print 4321 if worked
    {
        std::cout<<d->x;
        d=d->inner;
    }
    getchar();
    delete c;
    d=NULL;
    c=NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

**But this works:**

```
// atom.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

class a
{
public:
    int x;
    a * inner;
    a * outer;
    a(int n)   //creates an inner a
    {
        n--;
        x=n;    
        if(n>0){inner=new a(n);inner->outer=this;}else{inner=NULL;} 
        //works without error
    }

};

int main()
{
    a * c=new a(5);
    a * d=c;
    while((d->inner))     //prints 4321
    {
        std::cout<<d->x;
        d=d->inner;
    }
    getchar();
    delete c;
    d=NULL;
    c=NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Do you think all they are auto-deletet when i just delete c  ?

Comment: What in your experience would lead to suspect this kind of *auto*-deletion feature?

Comment: They start auto-destruting until they reach NULL? maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do this:

```
if(n>0)
{
   inner=new a(n); //first n is 4, then 3,2,1 and then 0
}
else
{
   inner=NULL;
}   
inner->outer=this;
```

the condition `n>0` will eventually not hold (at the 5th call), so `inner` will be `NULL`, and then you runt into undefined behavior (and the crash) when you attempt to dereference it (`inner->outer`).

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
inner->outer=this
```

needs to be inside the `if (n > 0)` branch, after the `inner = new a(n)` line, e.g.:

```
a(int n) : inner(0), outer(0) // set data members here
{
    x = --n;
    if (n > 0) {
        inner = new a(n);
        inner->outer = this;
    }
}
```

As written, when `n == 0` you're guaranteed a null-pointer exception when you try to set `NULL->outer = this`.